# Can I specify the path to biblatex annotation files

Tags: biblatex

The `biblatex` package allows you to write annotations to your bibliography as external files. I use those annotations to keep notes associated to the papers I read for my thesis.

Unfortunately, since the annotation of each bibliography entry has to be in a separate file, my TeX source directory gets quite cluttered. It would therefore be preferable if all annotations were in a separate directory but I cannot find a way to tell `biblatex` where to look for them. So my question is the following:

Is there any way to tell `biblatex` to look for the annotation files in a directory different from the current one?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Have you tried just using relative paths? I know, for example, that this works just fine with bibtex and the bibliography file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Joe's right, try putting your files in a common directory and use relative path from where your .tex document is.