# How to give the path of the .bib file in IEEEtran class?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

Please excuse me it's a naive question that I am unable to troubleshoot.

I am using the `IEEEtran` class with `\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}`.

The reference file is in a different folder location than the main Latex file.

My question is how to give the path of `.bib file` in the `\bibliography{ }` ?

I googled and tried the following formats but didn't succeed.

```
\bibliography{C:/Users/Dropbox (4)/Report-1/references.bib}{}

\bibliography{"C:/Users/Dropbox (4)/Report-1/references.bib"}{}

\bibliography{"C:\Dropbox(4)\Report-1\references.bib"}{}
```

Comment: Real quick: (a) `\bibliography` takes 1 argument, not 2. (b) Don't specify the filename extension, *viz.*, `.bib`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both but problem persist.

Comment: Check the answers to this question out https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46550/90297